# Wrong date with ruby Date.today and DateTime.now

Tags: ruby, datetime, date, rvm

I've installed ruby-1.8.6-p383 with RVM. System ruby is 1.9.1_p378-1

I'm getting the wrong date from Date.today and DateTime.now when using ruby 1.8.. Whereas Time.now is correct:

```
irb(main):002:0> DateTime.now.to_s
=> "2126--1-10618T11:23:43+00:00"
irb(main):004:0> Date.today.to_s
=> "2126--1-10618"
irb(main):005:0> Time.now
=> Thu Jan 28 11:55:27 +0000 2010
```

All is well if I switch to ruby 1.9:

```
irb(main):003:0> DateTime.now.to_s
=> "2010-01-28T11:58:51+00:00"
irb(main):004:0> Date.today.to_s
=> "2010-01-28"
irb(main):005:0> Time.now
=> 2010-01-28 11:59:05 +0000
```

Any advice on how to get DateTime to work properly in ruby 1.8 would be most appreciated!

Comment: I've installed ruby 1.8.7, which is returning the correct date.

Comment: seems to work fine for me ruby 1.8.6 p287 is using 1.8.6 a requirement for you?

Comment: I don't need 1.8.6, it's working with 1.8.7.. So I don't need to get this resolved.. It's just very strange! I only installed 1.8.6, because this is what rvm defaults to when doing "rvm install 1.8"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon similar problem and got 3 different solutions, which i tried 2 of and both worked. Read more about it from here:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/210647

Jarmo

Comment: Yes, I think the problem I was having was due to compiling with gcc 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

The returned string seems to be very broken: i) the year is 2126, ii) there's two hyphens between the year and the month, and ii) the day is 10618.

What platform are you on? What timezone are you on (the example implies you're in GMT)?

I'm on WinXP and Ruby 1.8.6-p111 gives the same result in all three cases.

Edit: I did some digging in the Ruby source code (`Date` and `DateTime` are defined in `lib/date.rb`).

It turns out that `Date.today` calls internally `Time.now.__send__(:to_date)...`, so maybe you should try calling `Time.now.__send__(:to_date).to_s` in `irb` and compare the output to `Time.now.to_s` in order to narrow down the problem.

`Date.today` also calls `.new_start(...)` on the created `Date` instance so maybe that's messing up the date in your case.

Comment: I'm using on linux x86_64.. I am in GMT.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure if you are running things locally, or on the server, but I think ruby might be taking the server date, which may be in a different time zone than you are, and thus, appear differently.