# Is there something wrong with this date comparison logic in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a policy class and in that class I have 2 methods which determin whether or not a customer can renew their policy.

They look like this: (in the policy.rb model)

```
  def is_renewable?
    if has_not_been_renewed?
       self.ends_on >= Date.today && self.ends_on <= Date.today + 60.days
    end
  end

  def has_not_been_renewed?
    been_renewed = self.renewed_policy.nil? || !self.renewed_policy.active? || !self.active?
  end
```

So for some reason this is working on my local machine but not in our staging enviroment. (I know right, the bane of every programmer "But it works on my machine!").

The logic seems simple: first check to make sure it hasn't been renewed already or that they have a different active policy. Then check to make sure it hasn't already expired and that it will expire sometime in the next 60 days.

This is called from this line in the view:

```
<%= link_to('Renew', {:action => 'renew', :id => policy.id}, {:class => 'btn btn-success'}) if policy.is_renewable? %>
```

I am really failing to see why this wouldn't work anywhere. I wouldn't ask but I have been looking at this stupid problem all day and need a new set of eyes to look it over. Thanks

Incase this helps, the format for both database's (local and staging) is in the form:
`yyyy-mm-dd` so today's date would be `2012-09-06`.

Comment: What does "working on my local machine but not in our staging enviroment" mean? Like the logic comes back incorrectly, or it raises an exception?

Comment: It comes back incorrectly, so testing use cases on my local machine it works great. Any policy that has expired doesn't have a renew button and any policy that will expire in the next 60 days does. And anything that would expire after 60days doesn't have a renew button either. On staging policies that have expired don't have a renew button(working as intended) but policies that will expire in the next 60days also don't have a renew button (not working as intended, they should have a renew button)

Comment: There's no need to set the variable `been_renewed` if it is the last statement in the method `has_not_been_renewed?`

Comment: Maybe this question will help? Are the servers on different Ruby versions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154281/wrong-date-with-ruby-date-today-and-datetime-now

Comment: @Adnan both systems are using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: @JoshuaCheek I thought of that when I went and checked on the date format. I even reset the timezone just to be sure they were the same.

Comment: Sorry, removed my comment before you responded b/c I saw that @Adnan basically said what I was thinking (I wrote it before lunch, but hit submit after >.<)

Comment: Would be helpful to run irb or rails console on both servers and capture `Date.today` output

Comment: @Adnan So..... I did that on my local machine then I ssh'd to the server went to the repository and typed in irb.... And it told me to install ruby. I didn't set the servers up so I don't know what the guy did but I had assumed you had to have ruby installed on your server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have data integrity issues in you staging database (e.g. ends_on isn't being set, you think there should be a renewed policy when there isn't one), you might want to check the system clock and make sure it's both accurate and using the timezone you're expecting.

Comment: +1 for giving me a new idea to look into. I checked the staging database and the date format is the same as on my development machine. I'll post above what the format is.

Comment: I was actually referring to the actual values of the dates, not formatting issues.  Make sure you check for discrepancies between the datetimes you have in your DB, what you're expecting, and what Ruby's using (which should be in line with your system clock), and the zone issue.  If, for instance, your staging machine is set to UTC and you're in PDT, `Date.today` may not return the value you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Is policy on a database (and the db differ in your staging and development environment)? In some cases you should format dates in a format more digetible to database, such as 
Time.now.to_s(:db)